# Check class object count in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to solve a memory leak problem in Swift. Supposedly there should only be one instance of a specific subclass of UIViewController at a given time. I tried detecting object count by making a static variable that tracks creation and deletion. See below code for sample code:

```
 class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    #if DEBUG
    static var objectCount:Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            println("\(toString(self)) Count: \(objectCount)")
        }
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        LoginViewController.objectCount++
    }

    deinit {
        LoginViewController.objectCount--
    }
    #endif
}
```

Considering that I have a big storyboard, it's not practical to copy-paste these lines to each of my view controllers. Is there anyway I can count object instances in a more convenient way? If not, is there a way to apply this line of code to each of my view controllers without having to modify each one?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Instruments Leaks template. It is already doing this work for you.